# MS Excel Currency Rounding Method

Tags: c#, excel, rounding, currency

Would like to know which rounding method is applied when you use Round() function on Excel?
Also is there a difference when you choose to format a column as currency with two decimal places.
I need to emulate Excel's results in a C# program I'm writing.

Comment: Have you done any testing yourself?

Answer (score 3):

Caution: Excel and Excel-VBA use two different algorithms.

In Excel:

`=ROUND(0.5,0)` returns 1.

`=ROUND(1.5,0)` returns 2.

In Excel-VBA:

```
Print Round(0.5,0)
 0 
Print Round(1.5,0)
 2
```

VBA uses banker's rounding: rounds 0.5's to the nearest *even* integer. Note that the same logic transfers to lower-order decimal places if you `Round` to more decimal places. For example, `Round(0.05,1)` returns zero in Excel-VBA (as opposed to 0.1 in Excel).

This is one of the features of VBA I dislike most. It being inconsistent with Excel makes it even worse.

The number format makes no difference to this issue.

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of this issue +1. In vba I would imagine using WorksheetFunction.Round(myRng, 0) might be a good alternative to keep it straight?

Comment: @datatoo: True, with the caveat that there is some overhead associated with accessing Excel's worksheet functions from VBA, which would affect performance if you were rounding *many* numbers. But if you're only using it a handful of times, it's fine, and `WorksheetFunction.Round(0.5, 0)` will return 1 as you would expect.

Comment: Another awful, ugly workaround is `CDbl(Format(0.5, "0"))`, i.e. convert to string using `Format` (which, contrary to `Round`, doesn't use banker's rounding for some reason) and then back to `Double` using `CDbl`.  Amazingly, this is faster than `WorksheetFunction.Round`! Rounding 10 million numbers in VBA on my old machine took 2 seconds with `Round` (which is fast but uses stupid banker's rounding), 20 seconds using `CDbl(Format(0.5, "0"))`, and all of 30 seconds using `WorksheetFunction.Round`!